# is it possible for python to make an occlusion image?

Tags: python

i wonder is python can make an occlusion image for example:

from this image:
[normal photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfyXC.jpg)

to this image:
[occluded photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLXbL.png)

if this possible, how to do it? any answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OpenCV and the `rectangle` function (see doc [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)).
For example this code will occlude half of the image:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np 

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
h, w, _ = image.shape
out_image = cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (w // 2, h), (0, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do image processing in Python.
In your case, I would take a look at [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) and, in particular, the [draw.rectangle](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.rectangle) function.

One question is to determine the coordinates of the zone you want to occlude but that really depends on your specific application.